# SignalR Error 405 (method not allowed) - Negotiate

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.2

here below my envirovment:

- Web Client Javascript with **Mvc .NetCore 2.2**
- WebAPI in **Web api .Net Core 2.2**
- AzureAd Authentication with openid

We have some trouble with SignalR connection.

With the **Attempt 1** we are able to use correctly signalR in our development environment (localhost), but when we deploy it in production we received the error:

"**WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxxxxx:60000/PushNotificationHub?access_token=' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400**"

**Attempt 1**

```
connessioneServizioChat = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(puntatori.url.applicazioneApiCore + "PushNotificationHub", {
            accessTokenFactory: () => sicurezza.dati.tokenAutenticazioneWebApi,
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
        }).build();
```

So we are trying to avoid the "websocket" transport type with the solution below:

```
 connessioneServizioChat = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(puntatori.url.applicazioneApiCore + "PushNotificationHub")
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();
```

In this case we have an issue in the development environment too:

**signalrNew.min.js:16 OPTIONS https://localhost:60000/PushNotificationHub/negotiate 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

We don't understand WHAT is the negotiate method and how to solve our issue.

Can someone help us?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days we found the solution. 
The problem was the Server IIS.
In our test server we had windows server 2008 with IIS 7.5. But IIS 7.5 doesn't support [WebSocket because it was introduced with IIS 8.0.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket)