# Signalr hosted on Azure gives 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-5.0

Trying to deploy my website to Azure, Signalr gives the following errors on the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

For this call:

```
hubs/presence/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1:1
```

Followed by:

```
Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.: Status code '405'
```

Here are the endpoints:

```
app
                .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapHub<PresenceHub>("hubs/presence");
                });
```

The website works on https, and the urls are defined as follows:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl:'https://vidcallme.azurewebsites.net/api/',
  hubUrl:'https://vidcallme.com/hubs/',
  baseUrl:'/'
};
```

The api works, the hub doesn't.

Here's the Api web.config

```
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\API.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
```

The client is written with Angular.

Here is my client web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />   
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
              <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
            </verbs>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
      
      
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Related:
[SignalR Error 405 (method not allowed) - Negotiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925264/signalr-error-405-method-not-allowed-negotiate)

Comment: Have you enabled WebSockets on App Service (if running there)?

Comment: not aware of that.. I'll google :) thanks

Comment: I've enabled web sockets. Still same error

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your side. It shows `Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE`, except `POST`. This is the reason.

[image]

*You can refer below code.*

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
      <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
    </verbs>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving so much effort into it! I've changed the client web.config, but still it doesn't work. I've added it to the question. I've also changed the api's web.config, just to make sure.. but the allowed verbs hasn't changed. I'm a complete ignorant on how the web.config works, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: @OrenA The http [405 error was fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8nR0.png),  now your site has some issue, that's why the guest18 user can't be authorized.

Comment: the original error still happens. I think you're getting 401 because your session has expired, but I signed out and back in, and I still get the original 405 Method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was at the enviorment.prod.ts.
Should look like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl:'https://vidcallme.azurewebsites.net/api/',
  hubUrl:'https://vidcallme.azurewebsites.net/hubs/',
  baseUrl:'/'
};
```